# Disable editing of geometry in Geoexplorer, allowing only the editing of attributes for specific layer?

Tags: geoexplorer

I wonder if, for a specific layer, it is possible in Geoexplorer to disable the editing of the geometry but still been able to edit the attributes related to the geometry (attributes edit popup).

I know that it's possible to exclude some of the attributes using **excludeFields**

(excludeFields
Array Optional list of field names (case sensitive) that are to be excluded from the property grid of the FeatureEditPopup.
http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/doc/lib/plugins/FeatureEditor.html)